# Docker not starting, hard to debug

Tags: mysql, docker

I am trying to start a docker image as follows:

```
docker run -i -t myimage:test
```

The image contains a mysql with `/var/lib` inside of the image. When the docker is run, it outputs this:

```
$ docker run -i -t myimage:test
2018-02-07T13:00:21.318700Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2018-02-07T13:00:21.337000Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2018-02-07T13:00:33.496999Z mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
$
```

It is very hard to see what is wrong in the image as one cannot enter and see the detailed logs. This is my image, I guess I have done something wrong during building it, but without logs, it is hard to find out what.

Comment: [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/0) might help you out. Just be sure the image is running. Alternatively you can pass a CMD override to the `docker run` like so: `docker run -it myimage:test /bin/bash`, but note this will override any existing CMD.

Comment: If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) might help you out. Just be sure the image is running. Alternatively you can pass a CMD override to the docker run like so: `docker run -it myimage:test /bin/bash`, but note this will override any existing CMD